# How to build a SQL query in Laravel 5 using join and whereNotIn in a controller?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to build the following Query in Laravel Controller.
Query:

```
select * from table2 where id not in (select table2.id from table2 inner join table1 on table2.id = table1.id)
```

I done this:

```
$cond = DB::table('table2')
->whereNotIn('id', function($query){
     $query->select(DB::raw('table2.id'))
     ->from('table2 inner join table1 on table2.id = table1.id');
})->get();
```

Please, help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cond = DB::table('table2')->whereNotIn('id', function($sq) { 
    $sq->select('table2.id')
       ->from('table2')
       ->join('table1', 'table2.id', '=', 'table1.id'); 
})->get();
```

Comment: @BNRNANI glad to help! you can accept answer for further readers if it was helpful :)